# Should I put my test method in a separate class? If so, how?

Tags: java, class

I am very new to Java. My assignment is to create my own method and then create a class to test it in.
My question, do I create the method separate of the class, or within the class? If it is separate of the class, how do I get the class to access my method?

(Are they saved as two separate files?)

This is what I have so far, but I am getting an error that I have to initialize KILOWATT in class DWindmill. I thought I did already in the method??? Any suggestions?

```
//This is the method Windmill

import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

class DWindmill {



    public static void Windmill(){
    //create the method for the Windmill class

    int miles = 50;
    //int miles = 200;
    //int miles = 250;
    int KILOWATT = (miles / 50);}


    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    {


    System.out.println("Enter miles per hour:");
    miles = console.nextInt();

    Windmill();

    System.out.println(+ KILOWATT + "kilowatts");

    }
}
```

Comment: You should show us what you have already.

Comment: Jennifer - if that is your real name - you should actually go to the Java classes, not just call classmates for assignments. Methods can only exist within a class in Java. Classes are composed of data members and methods. This would have been covered in the first five minutes of the first class.

Comment: Don't you have *any* textbooks to refer to? Try here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/index.html

Answer (score 6):

For a simple assignment such as this, you can probably create your method in the same class as your class.  Create a class with a static main method, which will be your programs starting point, and then create your method which will be called.

Seems like you are quite new to programming I would take advantage of any tutorials that are offered in your program.  They are usually taught by junior, senior, or grad level students, and are meant to give you a good introduction to the material, as well as give you time outside class to ask questions.  Make sure you go to class, and try to read the textbook you were supposed to buy for the course.  The information can often be found there.

Answer (score 4):

**please** go to class or read a textbook or something because your code illustrates
a fundamental misunderstanding of what a class is, what a method is, and
how to use braces for code blocks. Here is a corrected (but untested) version of
your code -

```
class Windmill
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter miles per hour:");
        int miles = console.nextInt();
        int KILOWATT = (miles / 50);
        System.out.println(KILOWATT + " kilowatts");
    }
}
```

seriously, [anything](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html) should be helpful at this point

Answer (score 2):

In Java, ALL methods exist within classes.  So in order to create a class, you write something like:

```
public class MyClass {

   public static void Hello() {
      //This is your method!
   }

   public static void main (String[] args) {
       Hello();  //This is how you call your method.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OR you can create like follows

```
public class MyClass {
  public int myMethod() {
    ,,,,,
  }
}

public class myTest {
  public void testMyMethod() {
   MyClass testClass = new MyClass();
   int output = testClass.myMethod();
 . 
. 
  }
}
```

In Java, all methods need to be inside a class. You can have a separate test class or test it in the same class.

Things can get more complicated if you use something like jUnit(www.junit.org) for unit testing your methods.